# insert text as guid to binary (16)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

my table guid column type binary (16).
No problem when I send guid value with parameter.
But I sent guid value as sql text,  I'm getting an error(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Data too long for column).

```
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`GuidId`) VALUES ('30ec1950-c0da-4498-9aa6-685a83c74441');
```

I have tried the following but this time it is corrupted

```
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`CustomerGuid`) VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE('30ec1950-c0da-4498-9aa6-685a83c74441', '-','')));
```

My value :       '30ec1950-c0da-4498-9aa6-685a83c74441'
inserted value : '5019ec30-dac0-9844-9aa6-685a83c74441'

how to add in the right way?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customerid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customerguid binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    firstname varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    lastname varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    createddate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerid),
    KEY ix_tmp_autoinc (customerid)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=34
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SOLUTION:

https://gist.github.com/IcyMidnight/159151

the problem is solved with the functions on this link. Two functions work correctly.

```
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`CustomerGuid`) VALUES (uuid_to_bin('d8faa5d2-a445-4ee3-a35d-33e7b8c68e67'));
```

Comment: Please show us you table. `desc customer`

Comment: How do you map your GUID to the storage in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that your existing code *might be "right"*, for some value of "right". It could be simply that the code you're using to read the guid disagrees on the encoding layout.

---

I would suggest using a parameter and sending either a guid *itself*, or (preferably): sending a `byte[]`. For example:

```
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`GuidId`) VALUES (@val);
```

with

```
Guid guid = ...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", guid);
```

or

```
Guid guid = ...
byte[] bytes = (your choice of encoding of guid)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", bytes);
```

Importantly, note that guid encoding **is ambiguous**. There are two commonly used formats with different layouts, so understanding where each part of the guid should end up is importantly. Worse: different ADO.NET providers and RDBMS *disagree* - hence the most reliably approach is to talk in `byte[]`, not `Guid`. Once the data is a `byte[]`, it is hard to argue about the order.

Specifically, the guid:

```
00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff
```

can be encoded as **either** big-endian:

```
00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
```

**or** mixed-endian:

```
33 22 11 00 55 44 77 66 88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
```

Obviously, if your read and write code disagree: bad things happen.

Comment: I use MySql.Data.MySqlClient as a provider. 
No problem with Parameter but I can not send sql text.
how can I do Guid string to binary(16) format

Comment: @KorkutDüzay which format did you want? as I said: there are two

Comment: format big-endian.

which MySQL method can convert correctly UNHEX() method alternative

Comment: @KorkutDüzay you wouldn't use unhex if you've already encoded it... but: `var arr = guid.ToByteArray(); Array.Reverse(arr, 0, 4); Array.Reverse(arr, 4, 2); Array.Reverse(arr, 6, 2);` - your array is now the guid expressed as big-endian

Comment: I am send text '30ec1950-c0da-4498-9aa6-685a83c74441' mysql not inserted. but UNHEX(REPLACE('30ec1950-c0da-4498-9aa6-685a83c74441', '-','')) inserted in table. but encoded problem select query guid => reader.getGuid('CustomerGuid') value received  '5019ec30-dac0-9844-9aa6-685a83c74441'

Comment: @KorkutDüzay unhex doesn't convert order, so that will end up big-endian; it sounds like `reader.getGuid` is expecting mixed-endian; so: *stop using unhex here*, and either use a guid (my first example) or just use `guid.ToByteArray()` (which produces mixed-endian) and pass in the raw bytes

Comment: @KorkutDüzay ultimately, the problem here is that the read code and the write code need to match. Right now you're using big-endian write and mixed-endian read, so: bad things. You either need to use mixed-endian write (`ToByteArray()`), or a big-endian read (read the bytes manually, reverse 0/4, 4/2, 6/2
, pass that to the `Guid` ctor)

Comment: thanks for your help. I solved the problem and I wrote the solution up.